# inline block with pintrest like boards

Tags: html, css

I want the inner div to flow to top automatically.Like **Pintrest UI**

http://jsfiddle.net/zbbHc/127/

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="iB">Content<br>Content<br>Content<br></div>
<div class="iB">Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br></div>
<div class="iB">Content<br>Content<br>Content<br></div>
<div class="iB">Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br></div>
<div class="iB">Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br></div>
<div class="iB">Content<br>Content<br>Content<br></div>
<div class="iB">Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
width: 100%;
background: red;
text-align: center;
}

.iB {
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
width: 200px;

background: green;
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Comment: @FelipeAls I dont want whitespace on top!

Comment: Though I voted for duplicate, the only error-free solution there is Andrea Ligios solution where an HTML comment (or "gluing" end and start tags) is used. tl;dr solve it in HTML code not with CSS (something can always go wrong with CSS). No whitespace? Don't even write it in the first place

Comment: This isn't "whitespace" then. Look for `vertical-align` or Masonry as stated by Mr. Alien

Comment: @FelipeAls There is already a vertical-align

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are generating the HTML dynamically, just comment out the white space between the inline `div`s when you are generating the code.

### Demo

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="iB">Content<br>Content<br>Content<br></div><!--
    --><div class="iB">Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br></div><!--
    --><div class="iB">Content<br>Content<br>Content<br></div><!--
    --><div class="iB">Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br></div><!--
    --><div class="iB">Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br></div><!--
    --><div class="iB">Content<br>Content<br>Content<br></div><!--
    --><div class="iB">Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `display: block;` in conjunction with `float: left;` omits this problem. But that'll require some additional efforts to center the whole cluster.

Another workaround is masking the line breaks:

```
<div class="iB">Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br></div><!--
--><div class="iB">Content<br>Content<br>Content<br></div><!--
--><div class="iB">Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `font-size:0` to the parent element. Don't forget to define the `font-size` for child elements:

```css
.wrapper {
   font-size: 0px;
}

.iB {
    font-size:15px;
}
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/zbbHc/129/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for `margin-left:-4px;`

```
.iB {
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:-4px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/zbbHc/128/

**To remove the spacing on top**, you have to either use JavaScript, or reformat your everything into columns. This has some drawbacks, but it is a JS-free solution.

HTML

```
<div id="hold">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="iB">Content<br />Content<br />Content<br /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="iB">Content<br />Content<br />Content<br /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="iB">Content<br />Content<br />Content<br /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#hold{
     width:100%;   
}
.wrapper {
    float:left;
    width: 33%;
}

.iB {
    display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/zbbHc/131/